# how SignalR manages connection between multiple server using a back plane?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, websocket, signalr

how SignalR manages connections between multiple servers? as far as i know tcp connection (which is the underlying technology of websocket) has server affinity.

Comment: See following website.  I can explain any questions you may have : http://www.bloggedbychris.com/2013/10/31/signalr-overview-websockets-hubs/

Comment: the post you have linked is completely irrelevant. (super basic stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you fallback on using a "Backplane" to communicate with clients instead of direct server -> client communication. As you are aware, the normal, basic mode of SignalR is "sticky" in that it is between one server and the client, and switching to a new server isn't possible. This greatly impedes proper site scaling.

Theres a few different backplanes supported, including Redis, SQL, and Azure Service Bus.

See this article for a good overview of scaling out with SignalR:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: @SHM Basically by Connection Id, and you can also use a custom `UserIdProvider `. As I answered in your previous question, there is no "Server ID" in the connection Id. All messages are broadcasted to every server.